# Select dropdown in react with html in dropdowns

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I want to create a select dropdown in react where instead of regular options I want to show div containers with images. I need it because I want to have options with image on left and options stacked horizontally and vertically in a grid. Please see the image for reference. I want to know if I can do this using [React dropdown menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu).

*[image: Please see the image of how the dropdown should look.]*

Comment: You can't use Drop Down Menu from `material-ui` since it doesn't allow you to pass a custom component as Drop Down children. You can easily do your own or use [react-super-select](https://github.com/alsoscotland/react-super-select) or similar.

Comment: Thanks.. I am wondering if i can also customize as per the layout with options coming in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add image in label property of the dropdown options. React-select would handle it.

```
{
    label: (
      <div>
        <img
          src="Image_Source"
        />
       {text}
      </div>
    ),
    value: "Key",
  }
```